# How to sort a linked list in C

Tags: c

I am trying to sort a linked list but I'm not able to do it. I don't need to swap the nodes.
I've tried to solve the problem using an array-like sorting algorithm but it isn't correct

```
typedef struct list {
        char ch;
        int n;
        struct list *next;
    } List;

List *SortList (List *GeneralList)
{
    int swapped, TempN;
    char TempCh;
    List *Current=NULL;
    do
    {
        swapped=0;
        for (Current=GeneralList; Current->next==NULL; Current=Current->next)
        {
            if (Current->ch>Current->next->ch)
            {
                TempN=Current->n;
                TempCh=Current->ch;
                Current->n=Current->next->n;
                Current->ch=Current->next->ch;
                Current->next->n=TempN;
                Current->next->ch=TempCh;
            }
            swapped = 1;
        }
    }
    while (swapped==0);
    return GeneralList;
}
```

Comment: `for (Current=GeneralList; Current->next==NULL; Current=Current->next)` -> `for (Current=GeneralList; Current->next!=NULL; Current=Current->next)`. Also you shall check for the trivial case `GeneralList == NULL` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Sorting concatenated lists is relatively time-consuming, and methods that often need to access arbitrary elements are not suitable for this. Mergesort should be relatively easy to customize. Another option is to convert the list into an array, sort it, and create a list from the result.

Comment: Continuing with @clemens suggestion, the easiest way to accomplish the task would simply create an array of pointers to `List`, call `qsort` on the array and sort by `elem->c` or `elem->n`, then just re-wire the list iterating the sorted array setting `array[i]->next = array[i+1]`.

Comment: But, if you want to stick with what you have, you'll need to move the `swapped = 1` line inside of the `if` statement. Otherwise, the loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of sort you are doing could be very slow if you have many and many links.
If you are able to do it, I suggest you to do an insertion sort : Each time you get a link, place it at the right place in your linked list.

Here is a link that should be useful :
[Insertion sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort-for-singly-linked-list/)
But if you really want a bubble sort (useful if you don't have much links) :
[Bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-bubble-sort-linked-list/)

When I make linked list sort functions, I usually use a void func, that will take **list as parameter, so I can swap nodes in the function.

Hope I helped you, good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few changes to your code, and it should work now.
Please note the key changes:

- In the Boolean expressions, I've moved the values to the left side, so that an assignment won't happen by mistake
- The swap action was exported to an external function. I haven't changed your logic, though I do recommend to make a more generic swap function. If you haven't learned `void*` type yet, then perhaps export the internal logic to 2 functions, `Swap(int,int)` and `Swap(char,char)` and combine them in a `SwapNode(List*,List*)` function. The more functions the merrier!
- The `swapped` variable got it's name changed, to `swapFlag` so it'll be a bit more clear what it does. The change of it's value to `true` was moved inside the `if` statement, just after the actual swap.
- On the same topic, you'll want the loop to run while there are swaps happening. If the swap DIDN'T happen, then you stop.
- The `for` loop should run while the list doesn't end. The condition was changed accordingly.

Changes that I think you should consider:

- Consider changing the capitalization of letters depending on the word role. There are a few conventions out there. Try maybe doing all the variables with first letter small and the functions with the first letter Capital. It'll make your code much more readable.
- When writing functions, make the brackets look like this: `foo()` and not like this: `foo ()`. Also, much more readable.
- Don't be stingy with new lines or spaces. When everything crammed together, it makes it harder to see the different areas of your code.
- Think about using `#DEFINE` to use `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of `1` and `0`. Much more convenient.
- Consider checking the case when `GeneralList` sequels to `NULL` in the beginning.

Now for the code:

```
typedef struct List {
    char ch;
    int n;
    struct List *next;
} List;

void SwapNodeData( List* first, List* second )
{
    int  TempN;
    char TempCh;

    TempN      = first->n;
    TempCh     = first->ch;
    first->n   = second->n;
    first->ch  = second->ch;
    second->n  = TempN;
    second->ch = TempCh;
}

List* SortList(List* GeneralList)
{
    int   swapFlag;
    List* Current = NULL;

    do
    {
        swapFlag =0;
        for (Current = GeneralList; NULL != Current->next; Current = Current->next)
        {
            if (Current->ch > Current->next->ch)
            {
                SwapNodeData( Current, Current->next );
                swapFlag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while ( swapFlag );

    return GeneralList;
}
```